# Detailed Contribution Info Not Displayed

Tags: contributions, database

CiviCRM Version: 4.6.15
CMS: Drupal 7.43

I'm running into a weird bug and I'm not sure how to track it down. All of our old contributions (Pre 2014) don't show when you click on the the [contact] > [contributions] tab. It shows that they have made a contribution but doesn't list the detailed information.

I can confirm the data is in the civicrm_contribution table in our database. Is there anywhere else I can check?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check that your older financial types have the financial accounts that the system automatically associates when creating new financial types (e.g. income account, A/R account, etc.) - I have see this type of wacky sort of there but sort of not appearance occur when account relationships are not in place. After you add the required accounts, check to see if you see the older contributions on the contributions tab - if not, then it might be a different issue altogether.

Hope this helps!